# Confusion on Ablation test (Ablation Experiment or Ablation study)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, experiment-design, causality

I followed the steps of the ablation test to calculate the feature importance one by one.
In Table 1, row 1 presents the model prediction performance of using full features. Regarding rows 2-4, these are the model's performance after removing one certain feature. The result shows that the most significant decrease of model performance is in row 4, which means that Feature three is the most important feature contributing to the model prediction.

```
Table 1
| Feature               | Classification Accuracy | F1 score   |
| --------------------- | ----------------------- | -----------|
| 1. Full features      | 0.6705                  | 0.6103     |
| 2. Feature one        | 0.6737                  | 0.6131     |
| 3. Feature two        | 0.6701                  | 0.6092     |
| 4. **Feature three**  | **0.6662**              | **0.6009** |
```

Then, I add a new feature and redo the ablation test. I find that the most significant feature is Feature two rather than Feature three.

```
Table 2
| Feature                            | Accuracy   | F1 score   |
| ---------------------------------- | -----------| ---------- |
| 1. Full features                   | 0.6712     | 0.6138     |
| 2. Feature one                     | 0.6715     | 0.6109     |
| 3. **Feature two**                 | **0.6665** | **0.6071** |
| 4. Feature three                   | 0.6687     | 0.6073     |
| 5. Feature four (i.e., new feature)| 0.6705     | 0.6103     |
```

I'm quite confused about how to interpret the results...